# How to fix bug with CORS and cookies?

Tags: node.js, cookies, cross-domain

I am getting this error from the website

The set-cookie header didn't specify the same site attribute and was defaulted SameSite=Lax and it was blocked because it came from the cross-site response. The SameSite had to be set to SameSite=none to enable cross-site usage.

Please tell me how can I use cookie parser(set the correct argument) to set SameSite=none

My code is

```js
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: '*',
    credentials: true,
    methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'DELETE'],
  })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set sameSite to none then you need to set secure to true and cannot wildcard the origin like '*'.